# How to make specific columns as.numeric in R's data.table and keep the rest as it is?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose i have a following db:

```
db<-data.frame(para=c(round(rnorm(20,10,10),0)),sal1=c(rnorm(20,100,7)),sal2=c(rnorm(20,100,7)),sal3=c(rnorm(10,100,7)),sal4=rep(c("a","b"),5))

   para      sal1      sal2      sal3 sal4
1    -3  89.72090 105.79164 101.09462    a
2     3 102.64036 104.07501  96.41335    b
3    11 104.65196  90.49886 101.81897    a
4    27  99.61455 102.23207 108.41161    b
5    24 101.18734  98.16081 103.04760    a
```

and i want only sal1,sal2,sal3 as numeric and rest as is.
It should be generalised as i have 118 columns that i want as numeric and want to keep the rest as is.

I tried:

```
check<-names(db)
db<-db[as.numeric(get(check[which(check=="sal1"):(which(check=="sal1")+2)]))]
```

But i think this is just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `grep` to select the columns that start with 'sal', use that index to subset the 'db', loop through the columns, and convert to `numeric` assign the output to the 'db[nm1]`

```
 nm1 <- grep("^sal\\d+", names(db))
 db[nm1] <- lapply(db[nm1], as.numeric)
```

---

If we need it in `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(db)`), specify the columns in `.SDcols`, loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), convert to `numeric` and assign (`:=`) it back to same column names.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(db)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = nm1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this serves my purpose.

Comment: Hey when i converted using this "setDT(db)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = nm1]". since it was a factor, my 0's got converted into 1 and 1's got converted as 2. Any workaround for that? 
A quick help will be appreciated.

Comment: @AbhijeetArora  Okay in that case, you have to first convert to `character` and then to `numeric` i.e. `setDT(db)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))), .SDcols = nm1]`